# How to solve "cannot read property 'push' of undefined" in Firebug Lite?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firebug-lite

I'm using Chrome on OS X (Maverick) and got some issues opening Firebug Lite for testing an AngularJS application. There was a message:

```
cannot read property 'push' of undefined firebug-lite.js 30905
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: I passed 2 hours to find this solution on the web, this is for those who want to find it on stackoverflow

Comment: without a formal answer, this question will be automatically deleted.

Comment: Ok, sorry I just wanted to help.

Comment: I was suggesting that you move your answer to the answer block below.  You won't gain reputation for answering your own question, but the question will have an answer, which will keep it around longer.

Comment: I removed the answer from the question. @Laustralien As Joe suggested you should post it as an answer and not within the question. Doing so you can accept it and it makes it easier for people to find it.

Comment: I've improved your answer. You may accept it then...

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer in a [Firebug discussion group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/kZFrFIIeKM0/discussion).

Firebug Lite stores some info about its activation in the browser's local storage. To clear the local storage and by that reset the activation information execute this via the devtools' command line:

```
window.localStorage.clear()
```