# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn angular js .I am able to get output .But on console i am getting this error .How to remove this error ?

[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="ionic.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="">
    {{3+8}}

    </body>
    </html>
```

I just add two number using angular I am able to get expected result but getting this error on console.

Answer (score 5):

The error that you're seeing is stemming from a chrome extension that you have added on, namely firebug lite.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813886/how-to-solve-cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-in-firebug-lite) response, typing the following should correct that problem:

```
window.localStorage.clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

The error appears to have nothing to do with your code, but rather is an error in the programming of Firebug Lite, a browser extension.

Please can you disable or uninstall Firebug Lite, then refresh this page, and tell me what happens?